# print a sequence of numbers line by line with echo

Tags: bash, shell

I want to print each of the odd numbers from 1 to 99 on a new line, why doesn't this work in Bash?

`IFS=$'\n'; echo {1..99..2}`

It prints all the numbers on the same line, shouldn't IFS change this behavior?

Comment: `seq 1 2 99` does what you want.

Comment: What makes you think `echo` uses `$IFS` to separate its arguments?

Comment: Use `printf '%s\n' {1..99..2}`. You don't have to mess up with the `IFS`.

Comment: @SomayyahMohammed : `IFS`  controls the **parsing** of lines. The `I` stands for **Input**, not for Output....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo {1..99..2} | tr ' ' '\n'
```

You can get the same result using seq:

```
seq 1 2 99
```

Or, as Mr. Aydin suggests, it can be done with a single shell builtin using printf:

```
printf '%s\n' {1..99..2}
```

IFS controls the input parsing, and how bash detect a new line in the input. It is not important here.

Comment: Could be done in plain bash: `printf '%s\n' {1..99..2}`. An external command (`tr`) in a subshell isn't necessary for this task.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin printf is also external command. But yes, better one than two calls. Added to the answer.

Comment: `printf` is often a shell builtin, not an external command.

Comment: @WilliamPursell same as `tr` or `echo`, no? they have their executables in /bin

Comment: `which printf` -> `/usr/bin/printf` and `type printf` -> `printf is a shell builtin`  There is an external command `printf`, but my shell doesn't use it.   From 1998, I see a reference to printf as a bash builtin in the CHANGES file (cce855bc5)

Comment: Note that commit is just an import from bash-2.02, so printf has been a bash builtin for a very long time.

Comment: @JoseLinares `echo` is a builtin, `tr` is not, and `echo | tr` makes bash start two subprocesses (one for echo, one for tr) which is costly. All this is not necesary with `printf`. First command should be removed and `seq 1 2 99` should be added to your answer IMO (when it's done you get my vote).

Comment: `printf` is a shell builtin. See [Bash Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins).

Comment: okey, answer edited. Any other suggestion is welcome